# What is the rationale for a 6x6 truck chassis with 2 axles front vs. 6x6 chassis with 2 axles rear?

Tags: automotive-engineering

What is the rational for these two different 6x6 truck chassis arrangements? Is it merely a matter of intended distribution of weight across the chassis while in use?

As in, two axles up front to support a heavy engine, two axles in the rear for heavy cargo, or for towing a trailer?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the first Tatra have an articulating frame?

Comment: I'm not sure. If  you search for pictures of Tatra T815 you can find plenty of other examples: https://live.staticflickr.com/2506/4123910771_f3bee406c4_b.jpg

Comment: Okay, not an articulating frame. The first is intended as a prime mover with a 120 metric ton towing capacity. That requires a good bit of weight on the steering axles. In the case of the first photo, both front axles are steering axles to provide  sufficient steering control over the heavy truck/trailer combo.