# Why HMMWV's lights aren't located at the edges?

Tags: design, car, lighting

Hummvee has front lights located far from edges, closer to each other. That makes it harder to see edges of the vehicle in the dark.

Comment: @Downvoter If you think it's offtopic then cold you explain, please, how this differs from this: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/31600/what-is-the-rationale-for-a-6x6-truck-chassis-with-2-axles-front-vs-6x6-chassis

Answer (score 2):

The lights are mounted within specifications for positioning as required by laws in countries where they are used/sold.

Also, designers position them relating to the use the vehicle is likely to see, so if it is used through woods etc them the lights get mounted farther inboard so they get a bit more protection.

Comment: HMMWVs are exempt from all such regulations. I was an engineer in the motor vehicle logistics office of the USAF. I think the EPA did finally start buying vehicles that would pass emissions tests. But my info is dated, so perhaps some things have changed. We used to pay contractors to remove the catalytic converters (and the radio) from vehicles that got built with them. That was one of things I put a stop to, and added about $2000 to the DRMO auction value. We could sell some small pickups after three years for more than we paid for them.